# Composition algorithm in Javascript to return all possible compositions of a number

Tags: javascript, algorithm, combinatorics

**Edit:**

I need to implement composition algorithm in Javascript, where the result would be the same as [the figure on the right in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_%28number_theory%29#Examples).With a given number (`n`), the function would be able to return all possible separations, e.g.

```
2: [1,1], [2] (2 sets)
3: [1,1,1], [1,2], [2,1], [3] (4 sets)
4: [1,1,1,1], [1,1,2], [1,2,1], [2,1,1], [2,2], [3,1], [1,3], [4] (8 sets)
```

Ideally it should be a function accept and execute callback `2^(n-1)` times. I will accept answers in any language I could understand (and rewrite from). Thanks!

Comment: For the examples you gave for n=2, 3 or 4 it would be `2^(n-1)` wouldn't it?

Comment: @prusswan Thanks for the keyword. I've just written the function myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prusswan might have already given the best answer (the name of the algorithm), but I couldn't resist writing some javascript:

```
function separate(n, callback) {
    for (var i=1; i<n; i++) {
        separate(n-i, function(ret) {
            ret.push(i);
            callback(ret);
        });
    }
    callback([n]);
}
```

Comment: +1. That's very elegant. Not knowing anything about the algorithm the version I made up was 5 times as long (including two helper functions). I didn't think to use the callback to help do the processing.

Comment: This is a recursive solution which does not depend on using callbacks (but the other way being gluing result lists together, callbacks are arguably nice in this situation). Anyway, the key to it is that the function calls itself.

Comment: My version was recursive, but I had decided to have my function cache the results such that if you called it repeatedly for the same value of n it would get the result from the cache rather than recalculating from scratch. That also meant if the first call was for, say, n=8, when it returned that result the cache would also contain the results for n=7, n=6, n=5..n=2 because they'd get stored during the recursion. I pre-seeded the cache with the result for n=2. For n=3 I copied the result from n=2 and modified accordingly. And so forth.

Answer (score 1):

Just worked out the function on my own:

```
/* Return all possibile compositions of a given natural number
* callback will be called 2^n-1 times.
*
* ref: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(number_theory)
*/

function compositionsOf(n, callback) {
    var x, a, j;
    x = 1 << n-1;
    while (x--) {
        a = [1];
        j = 0;
        while (n-1 > j) {
            if (x & (1 << j)) {
                a[a.length-1]++;
            } else {
                a.push(1);
            }
            j++;
        }
        callback.call(this, a);
    }
};
```

Comment: Key knowledge to know from Wikipedia: "every composition matches a binary number".

Comment: nice, now I know how to do this in javascript (but hopefully I would never have to)

Answer (score 0):

```
def partition(i):
    lst = [1]
    while i:
        if i & 1:
            lst.append(1)
        else:
            lst[-1] += 1
        i >>= 1
    del lst[-1]
    return lst
```

Call for 2**(n-1) <= i < 2**n.